# How do I display a different chartjs tooltip title?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am displaying a mixed bar and line chart using chartjs. I have successfully managed to display different content in the tooltip when your hover over the line chart, or the bars, but using the same condition does not work to display a different title:

```
callbacks: {
  title: function(tooltipItem, data) {                      
     if (tooltipItem.datasetIndex === 0){
       return data['datasets'][0]['label'];
     }else{
       return data['datasets'][1]['label'];  
     }
   }
}
```

I am using PHP values to populate data into the main chart. Here is the code for the main chart:

```
var ctx_<?=$chartname?> = document.getElementById('<?=$chartname?>').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx_<?=$chartname?>, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: [<?=$labels?>], //label array needs to go here
        datasets: [{
                label: 'Overall Average Score',
                notes: ['','','','',''],
                data: [<?=$averages?>],
                pointBackgroundColor: '#6600CC',
                pointRadius: 6,
                pointBorderColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',    
                pointHoverRadius:8,
                pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
                pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)', 
                fill: false,
                
                // Changes this dataset to become a line
                type: 'line'
            },{
                label: '<?=$forename?>\'s Score',
                notes: [<?=$notes?>],
                data: [<?=$scores?>] //data array needs to go in here
            }],
    },
    options: groupBarChartOptions
});
```

However, instead of populating the tooltip title as 'Overall Average Score' it populates the line graph tooltip title of 'Pupil Name's Score'

I am using the same

```
if (tooltipItem.datasetIndex === 0){
```

condition in the following label callback, and it works.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for what you want:

```
title: (tooltipItem, data) => {
    return data['datasets'][tooltipItem[0].datasetIndex]['label']
}
```

working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/bcwky40z/4/